# Не правильно сравнивает элементы массива между собой

Tags: javascript

Суть задачи сравнить значения ключа language. Если они равны, то вернуть true иначе false. Почему в моей программе не правильно сравнивает?

```
function isSameLanguage(list) {
  let arr = [];
  let i = 0;
  let res = false;
  list.forEach(lang => {
      arr.push(lang.language);
      i++;
  })
  for (let j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++) {
    if(arr[j - 1] == arr[j]) {
      res = true;
    }
    else {
      res = false;
    }
  }
  if (res == true) {
    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;
}

let list1 = [{"firstName":"Mark","lastName":"G.","country":"Scotland","continent":"Europe","age":22,"language":"JavaScript"},
{"firstName":"Victoria","lastName":"T.","country":"Puerto Rico","continent":"Americas","age":30,"language":"Clojure"},
{"firstName":"Emma","lastName":"B.","country":"Norway","continent":"Europe","age":19,"language":"JavaScript"}]

alert(isSameLanguage(list1));
```

Comment: ну так у вас одно из значений Clojure. всё верно. будет false. потому что не все языки у вас одинаковые

Comment: Если вместо Clojure будет JavaScript все равно возвращает false

Comment: `if (res == true) {
    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;` --- эта конструкция вообще не имеет смысла, если тру- вернуть тру, если фолс - вернуть фолс....... ну смешно же))  напишите `return res;`

Comment: Отладка вам в помощь. Ссылка - в шапке вашего вопроса

Comment: `arr[j - 1] == arr[j]` — у вас ведь во время первой итерации `j` равно нулю, поэтому тут будет попытка сравнить `arr[-1]` и `arr[0]` — и  по отрицательному индексу всегда будет `undefined`.

Comment: Вдобавок у вас ещё такая ошибка в подходе: при текущем алгоритме достаточно одинаковых языков в последних двух элементах массива, чтобы функция вернула `true`. Вам проще пройтись по массиву и при первом же неравенстве вернуть `false`, обрывая уже ненужный дальше перебор. А если ни одного неравенства не было найдено, тогда вернуть `true` после цикла.